# Is it any way to see which data has been picked by the http request/api from csv data set config by Jmeter slave machines

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to see which data has been picked by the http request/api from  csv data set config by Jmeter slave machines as i have 55 users defined in the csv file and thread group users also 55, loop count 1 with ramp-up-period 5 and there is one more csv file which has ids 1 to 6 for another api. As per expectation it supposed to run for 55 times only, however it is running 110 times. When i run the same file with same setup from Jmeter GUI locally can see only 55 threads has been run. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each JMeter engine is totally independent, so

- if you have 55 threads defined in one [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) having one sampler and **1 slave** - you will have **55 requests**
- if you have 55 threads defined in one Thread group and **2 slaves** you will have **110 requests**
- if you have **3 slaves** - it will be **165 requests**
- etc.

You can use [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to add the variable from the CSV to the .jtl results file so you will be able to see the variable value for each and every request. The property can be defined either by adding the next line to *user.properties* file on each slave machine

```
#assuming your CSV Variable reference name is "foo"
sample_variables=foo
```

Alternatively you can pass it via -J command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=foo -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on working with different JMeter properties types

I would recommend adding [__machineName()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function to the Thread Group or Sampler label so you would be able to distinguish requests from difference slaves.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it is really useful and able to use it in my local successfully. However when running the command in slave machine as given above for sample_variables getting below message. Please suggest if I am doing something wrong. Mar 17, 2017 9:44:05 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
An error occurred:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.